# How to override store time config of a Kafka broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am reading Kafka documentation and it says it can store the topics for configurable time,

I have some questions

- what if the broker(s) run out of storage?
- Is there any way to suggest broker to discard the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the option to additionally configure the retention time by bytes retained with the property `log.retention.bytes`.

See documentation for `log.retention.{ms,minutes,hours}` and `log.retention.bytes` under [broker configuration](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs)